# What does the word [そうすっか」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

Here is the dialog containing the word. Is it a dialect?

> A: まあ　それじゃ一緒に食べない？
>
> B: **そうすっか**

Answer (score 2):

This is a colloquial form for 「する-か」． I don't think this is considered to be a particular dialect. (This form isn't used in western dialect, so it feels a bit eastern to my ear, just as the standard Japanese language does.)

In the dialog, A invites B to eat together, and B agrees (そうすっか == そうするか)． Other examples you might encounter is ~~でもすっか = でもするか.