# Are すっど and すっがら contractions of すると and するから?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, dialects, contractions

I encountered these words in トロ子’s speech in a game 洞窟物語 / Cave Story.

> …あたしがスーと仲良くすっどキングが機嫌悪くすっがら。

I am not really sure what the words `すっど` and `すっがら` are supposed to mean. I guess they are contractions from `する` + `と` and `から`. The sentence would make some sense to me like that.

I am not sure however. What makes me doubt is the vocalization of the `と` and `から`. In a similar [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84443/what-does-the-word-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B-mean), `する` was contracted to `すっ`, but without changing its following `か`.

Is this actually a contraction of `する` to `すっ`? What is the cause of the vocalization?

[image: だけど、もういらね。あたしがスーと仲良くすっどキングが機嫌悪くすっがら。]

#### Update

I did some research and found out that this may be mimic a dialect of northern Honshu.

- [Examples](https://www.hougen-love.com/dialect_miyagi/miyagi_wassha.php) of a word `わしゃ` from 宮城 contains both `すっど` and `すっがら` in expressions `ばりすっど` and `ばりすっがら` meaning `ばかりしていると` and `ばかりしているから` respectively.
- [A folk tale](https://www.yamagata-np.jp/minwa/minwa104.php) from 山形 contains both words. There is no translation.
- [An example](https://fukushimakenpoku.blogspot.com/2009/06/blog-post_16.html) of a word `でな` from 福島 contains `すっがら` translated as `するから`.

My question then remains. Is this contraction of `する` to `すっ` productive with vocalization of the following particle? What causes the vocalization then?

Comment: I think what causes the vocalization has been answered by your own research. That’s how they talk in the north.

Comment: FYI: http://www-solid.eps.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ataru/private/akitaben.html#dakuon

Comment: @aguijonazo The article on the Akita dialect show it well. `原則として「か」行と「た」行は濁音になる。` is pretty vague, but it has a lot of examples even containing `がら` a few times. `ど` is listed there only as a particle of coordination, not as a one of expression, but it’d still make some sense. トロ子 in the original source however does not use fully the dialect. But I guess that using it only for colloquial expressions like contractions and terminal particles is a way to add a slight flavor to the speech yet keeping it legible.

Answer (score 1):

すっがら is equivalent to するから here. I'm not sure why か became が, either an accent from the speaking character or some touch to make it cute.

Comment: Probably an accent.